What is the meaning of the words חציפא נצח לבישה
The Ramban, sidra Bo 13:16, writes as follows:

,וזו כוונתם במה שאמרו ז"ל (ירושלמי תענית פ"ב ה"א) ויקראו אל אלהים בחזקה (יונה ג ח), מכאן אתה למד שתפלה צריכה קול, חציפא נצח לבישה (עי' ערוך ערך חצף):


This is the intent of what the Rabbis of blessed memory have said (Yerushalmi Taanis 2:1): “And they cried mightily unto G-d" (Yona 3:8). From here you learn that prayer must be accompanied by sound. The undaunted one wins over the abashed one.”

What is the point which the ramban wishes to make with the last words "חציפא נצח לבישה"?

It is saying that a person has to demonstrate a bit of chutzpah - impudence when davening so that you don't hold back and pray out loud despite being in front of the King of Kings where the initial thought would be to exercise a degree of restraint.
The Dirshu website here explains it as follows:

בשבת האחרונה, שמעתי שדיבר הרה׳׳ג רבי אפרים וולך (המשגיח של 'ברכת אפרים') ובדיוק הוא דיבר על המילים הללו ברמב"ן הזה, ושאל מה ההסבר במילים האלו. והביא שר׳ ירוחם (פרשת כי תבא) והמשגיח ר׳ יחזקאל לוינשטיין מדברים על זה:
נצייר לעצמנו דוגמא: אדם בא למרן שה׳׳ת ר׳ חיים קנייבסקי שליט׳׳א והוא מאבד עשתונות ומתחיל לצעוק בקול: יש לי חולה בבית! שהרב יברך אותו!!! אז פשוט יגידו לו – לא ככה מדברים אל הרב, ויוציאו אותו מהבית… כאשר אדם בא לתפילה עם רוממות הקול, הוא צועק, עונה אמן יהא שמיה רבא בכל כחו! ההיגיון אומר: מה אתה צועק?… ככה מדברים אל המלך?!… שומעים אותך גם בלי צעקות… איפה הבושה מהקב׳׳ה?…
אומר ר׳ ירוחם – נכון, זו חוצפה, אך "חציפא נצח לבישה". אמנם זה בושה, לא ככה מדברים עם המלך, אך החוצפה ניצחה את הבושה. ולדוגמא, אדם שפסקו על אבא שלו גזר דין חמור, להתלות על עץ בכיכר העיר. הוא מנסה את כל ההשתדלויות, וככל שעובר הזמן הוא הפך עוד עולמות – ולא הועיל. אמרו לו יש לך רק אפשרות אחת, שהמלך יחון אותו. אבל זה מאד רחוק מ-2 סיבות: א) איך תגיע למלך. ב) למה שהמלך יחון אותו. הוא לא אוהב את היהודים יותר מהשופטים…
אך אותו בן לא אמר נואש. הוא הפעיל פרוטקציות והפך עולם, עד שסוף סוף קבעו לו פגישה אצל המלך כמה שעות לפני ביצוע הגזר דין. הוא בא אל המלך מתוך איבוד עשתונות, הוא פרץ בבכי מתוך צעקות רמות – המלך! תציל את אבא שלי!!! אני לא שולט בעצמי לא לצעוק, אני צועק כי אני יודע שאנחנו בידיים שלך! רק אתה יכול!!! עוד כמה שעות, או שאבא תלוי בכיכר העיר, או שאתה חונן אותנו והוא יחזור אלינו. תרחם עלינו! תציל אותנו! זעק. כולם מבינים את זה… זה פורץ לו…
אומר ר׳ ירוחם: אותו הדבר צריך יהודי להרגיש כשהוא בא לקדוש ברוך הוא. כל החיים שלי בידיים שלך! החיים, הבריאות, פרנסה, שכל, הורים, חברותא, הכל בידיים שלך, ורק אתה יכול לעזור לי, אם אתה לא עוזר לי חלילה, אני אבוד לגמרי! את זה אני צועק להקב׳׳ה. אמנם זו בושה, אך החוצפה נצחה לבושה, והקב׳׳ה אוהב את זה, שיהודי מרגיש שכולו תלוי רק ביד ה׳
Last Shabbos, I heard Rabbi Ephraim Wallach (the Mashgiach of Bircas Ephraim) speak, and he spoke precisely about these words in this Ramban, and asked what the explanation was in these words. And he brought Rav Yerucham (parshas Ki Savo) and the Mashgiach Rabbi Yechezkel Levinstein speaks about it.
Let's draw an example for ourselves: a man comes to Maran Rav Chaim Kanievsky Shlit'a (now sadly zt"l) and he loses his temper and starts shouting loudly: I have a sick person at home! May the Rabbi bless him!!! Then they will simply tell him - that's not how you talk to the Rov, and they will escort him out of the house... When a person comes to prayer with his voice raised, he shouts, answers Amen, may the heavens be great in all his might! Logic says: What are you shouting?... Is this how you talk to the King?!... You are heard even without shouting... Where is the shame from G-d?...
Rav Yerucham says - correct this is deemed chutzpah. However, "The undaunted one wins over the abashed one". Although it's a shame, that's not how you talk to the King, but the sheer audacity overpowers the shame. And for example, a man whose father was given a severe sentence, to be hanged from a tree in the city square. He tries all the efforts, and as time goes by, he goes above and beyond - and still to no avail. They told him you have only one option, that the king will pardon him. But it is very far for 2 reasons: a) How will you get to the king. b) Why should the king pardon him. He does not like the Jews more than the judges...
But that son did not give up hope. He exercised some protekzia, managing to somehow flip the odds, until finally they made an appointment with the king a few hours before the execution of the sentence. He came to the king out of losing his temper, he burst into tears out of loud shouts - the king! save my father! I can't control myself not to shout, I shout because I know we are in your hands! Only you can!!! In a few more hours, either father will be hanging in the city square, or you will bail us out and he will return to us. Have mercy on us! Save us!" He cries out. Everyone understands this... it breaks him...
Rav Yerucham says: A Jew should feel the same when he comes to the Holy One, blessed be He. My whole life is in your hands! Life, health, livelihood, intellect, parents, chavrusos, everything is in your hands, and only you can help me, if you don't help me, G-d forbid, I'm completely lost! This is what I shout to G-d. Although it is a shame, but insolence beats shame, and G-d loves it, that a Jew feels that everything depends only on G-d's hand.


In your first paragraph - are you saying that one should or should not raise ones voice in prayer?

One should raise their voice that's the whole point.

This is a variant of the phrase חציפא נצח לכשירא, i.e. "the one with chutzpa beats the proper one". See Yerushalmi 2:1, which teaches a lesson that the people of Ninveh did teshuva by "blackmailing" Hashem, separating their calves from their mothers and saying "if you don't answer our cry, we will not answer theirs", and it worked.
The gemara then says כָּל־שֶׁכֵּן לְטוֹבָתוֹ שֶׁלְעוֹלָם, "all the more so, for the good of the world" i.e. one who uses this "chutzpadik" method of entreating Hashem will have his prayer answered.
This Ramban is making a startling connection between this concept, and the very reason for creating the world! I.e. that Hashem created the world so that He should have creations that pray and admit their gratitude to Him for creating them. They should do so loudly, unabashed!
[I think a good mashal is, when we creations do consider how much we are grateful to Hashem, our gratitude shouldn't paralyze us with shame, but energise is with joy!]

I wonder whether בישה (timid) was meant as a pun on בישא (bad), the opposite of כשירא.

@msh210 I don't have any evidence for that theory, but if you find any let me know. בישה is considered a very noble trait.

Of course it is. I didn't mean that בישה here means something bad. I meant only that I wonder whether he chose that specific word in the phrase to make the phrase sound like a counterpart to the original.

@msh210 yes that's actually fascinating and also possibly explains why that word is switched to hebrew

See how gut wrenching a cow that cries for its separated calf: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zjESNyK_84Y
